# Does short circuit always (in every electronic circuit) shunt the resistor that has both sides connected to the short circuit branch?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, shunt

I wanted to know if short link always (in every electronic circuit) shunt the resistor that has both sides connected to the short link branch

Comment: Not every electronic circuit has resistors.

Comment: Of course not, I was asking for the ones that have. It's impossible to shunt something that doesn't exist in that circuit

Comment: I think you'll have to reword your question with maybe a diagram or schematic, as it is it's unclear what you're asking.  As @EugeneSh. pointed out not every circuit has resistors.

Comment: By definition, a short circuit is a fault that shunts some part of your circuit. Are you asking does a fault that shunts some part of your circuit shunt that part of your circuit?

Answer (score 1):

> Does short circuit always ... shunt the resistor that has both sides connected to the short circuit branch?

For most low-frequency circuits, yes. (At high frequencies other effects come into play.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6HTPX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuits.*

Both ends of R2 are at the same potential due to the shorting link. Since they are at the same potential no current will flow through R2 so it doesn't make any difference if it is in or out of circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTEv2S.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. How quickly can you figure out the resistance between A and B?*

Hint: remove the resistors that are short-circuited.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are asking: When is a shorting wire not a dead short? Any real world length of wire has resistance and reactance which at some frequency becomes non-negligible. If a shorting wire is an appreciable percentage of a wavelength, it is not a short-circuit. For instance, the 1 inch wire that I use for a short-circuit on 10 MHz would be a 1/4WL open-circuit on 3 Ghz. The lumped constant model of zero ohms works well at 10 MHz but at 3 GHZ we are forced to use the distributed network model or Maxwell's equations.